# Simple file uploading using Flex only?

Tags: apache-flex

/*Flex code*/

```
       private const UPLOAD_URL:String = "http://myhosting/upload/upload.php";
       private var cer:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Archivos Cer", "*.cer");
       private var key:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Archivos Key", "*.key");
       private var fileref:FileReference = new FileReference();
       private var fileref2:FileReference =  new FileReference();


protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void

{  


    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
 request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
 request.url = UPLOAD_URL;
 fileref.upload(request);
 fileref2.upload(request);

}
```

Well, that's the procedure I use to get my files up my server. The "upload.php" in my server is:

```
<?php 
 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
 } 
 else {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 }
 ?>
```

Is there a way to do this in FLEX only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, without PHP or some other server-side code? No, you can't. You need some code on the server which can accept the uploaded file.

Comment: David, wouldn't you know the simpliest way in java to do the same thing php does in my example?

Comment: I wouldn't, sorry… But I suspect that it would depend mostly on the Java framework you're using.